Attributes not saving with object initialization
I want to create a person object with random attributes like height and weight. I am adding this logic in my object class under my getters. I can see auto-generated attributes when running this code, but they do not seem to be keeping their values. How do I properly set these values when I run the code, and am I checking properly to see those values? I plan to use String arraylists for other attributes, so I wanted to include an example here for weight.
package com.rpg;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Sim2 implements Comparable<Sim2>{

    private int height;
    private String weight;

    public Sim2(int height, String weight)
    {
        super();
        this.height = height;
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public int getHeight()
    {
        double randomInches = Math.random() * (70 - 60 + 1) + 60;
        height = (int)randomInches;
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(int height)
    {
        this.height = getHeight();
    }

    public String getWeight()
    {
        List<String> weightLbs = new ArrayList<String>();
        weightLbs.add("125 lbs");
        weightLbs.add("145 lbs");
        weightLbs.add("165 lbs");
        weightLbs.add("185 lbs");
        int randomIndex = (int) (Math.random() * weightLbs.size());
        return weightLbs.get(randomIndex);
    }

    public void setWeight(String weight)
    {
        this.weight = getWeight();
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Sim2 o)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Sim2 [height= " + getHeight() + ", weight= " + getWeight()+ "]";
    }
}

package com.rpg;

public class Driver2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Sim2 npChar = new Sim2(0,null);
        System.out.println(npChar);
        System.out.println(npChar.getHeight());
        System.out.println(npChar.getWeight());
    }
}


but they do not seem to be keeping their values They won't do, since you're generating random values in the accessors. They'll be different every time they are called. You call them once in toString and then again. btw this functionality should be kept well away from the bean itself, in a separate class
